# Does NotificationManagerCompat only have wear-specific features in relation to NotificationManager?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

The Android tutorials say to use `NotificationManagerCompat` class to show notifications, but since this class has no `createNotificationChannels` method, it's a bit awkward to handle 2 different `NotificationManager`s.

From my search online it seems that all internal features of `NotificationManagerCompat` are specific to Android Wear and have no effect on phone/tablet. Is that observation correct?

Answer (score 0):

As stated the NotificationManagerCompat is a "Compatibility library for NotificationManager with fallbacks for older platforms."

It holds in it and IMPL class that behaves differently according to the platform it is installed upon.
you can have a look at:
[NotificationManagerCompat.java](http://%20https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/%2B/cef09fe/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.java)

I'm not sure how differently it behaves but what it actually does is overrides certain methods that deal with posting, canceling and checking if notifications are enabled.