# What differences between NotificationManager and NotificationManagerCompat?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am able to create notification so:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 if (notificationManager != null) {
     notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
 }
```

and so:

```
 NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
 notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

So, what differences between these ways?

Comment: If you check the source code of `NotificationManagerCompat` it is using `NotificationManager` behind the scene.

Comment: See this answer for a similar question: [Does NotificationManagerCompat only have wear-specific features in relation to NotificationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192724/does-notificationmanagercompat-only-have-wear-specific-features-in-relation-to-n/52575832#52575832)

Answer (score 6):

`NotificationManagerCompat` is a compatibility library for `NotificationManager` with fallbacks for older platforms.

I encourage you to take a look at the `NotificationManagerCompat` class since there are many different adjustments.

Generally almost all functions in `NotificationManagerCompat` call a compatible function in the `NotificationManager`.

For example function `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` check for a flag `EXTRA_USE_SIDE_CHANNEL`. If it is `false` - the function simply calls `NotificationManager.notify()`. If set to `true`, the posted notification should use the side channel for delivery instead of using notification manager(Maximum sdk build version which needs support for side channeled notifications is API 19).